# Software to adjust display brightness on Windows XP laptops

Tags: windows-xp, display

Is there any software to adjust display brightness on laptops on Windows XP? Windows mobility center on Windows 7 is really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a lot of great experience with this software [**PowerStrip**](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)

Comment: this is really good..has a lot of other features. Let me try this out

Answer (score 3):

Some laptop manufacturers offer utilities for download to control screen brightness and other features of the laptop.  For example Dell has something called "Dell QuickSet" which controls the brightness using the special blue Fn key in combination with the up and down arrow keys.  (http://support.dell.com/support/index.aspx?c=ca&cs=cadhs1&l=en&s=dhs&~ck=mn click on Drivers and Downloads, specify your model)

Comment: most laptops have Fn key combinations, but i want to do it from software...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adjusting brightness? If it's because, as the day goes by, lighting changes and your screen becomes difficult to see, try [f.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/). It has Windows, and Linux versions, and is brilliant software. Completely unnoticable when it's on, but when it's off, you know what you're missing.

F.lux changes the colour warmth of your screen to match the sun, which is pretty nice. It's all very slick, no messing around with configuration every day to keep it in sync, it uses your latitude to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and, while keeping it pressed, try all keys with an icon that looks like the sun.

Specifically on Acer laptops (I'm using Aspire 4736Z), it is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to decrease brightness, and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to increase brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I use this minimal app that sits in the system tray and pops up a slider when you click.
http://www.ookii.org/software/#Brightness

And interesting thing is that XP stores separate brightness settings for battery and plugged in even though you can't set it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

MonitorBright works on my Windows 8 desktop and and Win8 Thinkpad Tablet 2. http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/monitorBright.shtml

Other compatible OSes: Windows 2K / XP / Vista